# Windows API to query installed features and packages

Tags: winapi, dism

For one of my projects, I need a way to query which features/roles/role services are installed on a given Windows Server machine.

In it's grand tradition, Microsoft keeps reinventing stuff (`sysocmgr` in Windows 2003, `pkgmgr` and `ocsetup` in Windows 2008, `dism` in Windows 2012), making it hard to write OS-independent code.

I know for sure that there is an official native API for DISM (and a [managed wrapper](https://manageddism.codeplex.com/)). Is there something for Windows 2003 and 2008?

Answer (score 0):

WMI has the [Server Feature Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280267%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for Windows Server 2008 and above.  If you're still running Windows Server 2003, it's out of support, and you *really* need to migrate.

Comment: downvoter here, really, what good pushing migration does to this answer? I think "it's out of support." would be informative enough.

Comment: @naxa I'd recommend *anyone* running a 12 year old OS to migrate to something newer; be it windows, Linux, or BeOS.

Comment: Well not that important really; My point is someone like the OP having both 2003 or 2008 must have the technical insight from the expertise so is a) either oblivious of the fact that support has gone from w2003 or b) already aware of special requirements that keep the 2003 one around. Thus to stress migration without explicit rational -apart from the widely unspecific umbrella term that it's out of support- is a) either superfluous b) inherently uninformed. That's why I think the answer would be better off without the last part and best ended at `it's out of support`.

Comment: @naxa Then write your own answer.